# $\lim_ {n \to \infty} \int_{0}^{\infty} n\sin(x/n)(x(1+x^2))^{-1}dx$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, improper-integrals

I'm trying to compute $\lim_ {n \to \infty} \int_{0}^{\infty} n\sin(x/n)(x(1+x^2))^{-1}dx$. This is exercise 2.28c in Folland. I know all the big convergence theorems (dominated, monotone, etc.), but I'm not sure where to start with this problem. Any hints?

Comment: Hint rearrange the integrand apply DCT and a familiar limit.

Comment: I think I see it. $nsin(x/n) \leq x$ for nonnegative x. That'll cancel an x, and then the integral is just arctangent.

Comment: Hint: rewrite the integrand as $\frac{\operatorname{sinc}\frac{x}{n}}{1+x^2}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $$\mathcal{I}(a)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(ax)}{x(1+x^2)}dx$$ with $a>0$

differentiate booth sides by a we will get
$$\mathcal{I}'(a)=\int_{0}^\infty\frac{\cos(ax)}{1+x^2}dx$$ and now using cauchy Residue theorem we will get  $\mathcal{I}'(a)=\frac{\pi}{2e^a}$ and hence $\mathcal{I}=\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\pi}{2e^a}$

choose $a=\frac{1}{n}$ and $\lim n\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\pi e^{-1/n}}{2}\right)=\frac{\pi}{2}$

Comment: You can also evaluate $\mathcal{I}$ by the residue theorem directly, using $\sin ax=\Im(e^{iax}-1)$ to prevent a pole existing at $z=0$.

Comment: Actually yes but in that we need more clear calculations and i don't want to write all those things

Comment: Well, you didn't write it either way. Insofar as readers are invited to do it as an exercise, they can work with either. I'm just saying they needn't use differentiation under the integral sign.

Comment: Well i will write it properly 

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with the accepted answer except that I believe this exercise intends to test the understanding of convergence theorems. For the sake of completeness, let us fill in the details of the methods mentioned in the comments section.

The Dominated Convergence Theorem asserts that if there is a sequence $f_n$ of integrable functions $(i)$, such that $f_n \to f$ pointwise a.e. $(ii)$, and there exists a non-negative $g$ such that $|f_n| \lt g$ a.e. for all $n$ $(iii)$, then $\int f = lim_{n \to \infty} \int f_n$.

Let $f_{n}(x) = nsin(\frac{x}{n})[x(1+x^2)]^{-1}$, if one fixed $n \in \mathbb{N}$, note that
$nsin(\frac{x}{n})[x(1+x^2)]^{-1} \lt \frac{1}{1+x^2} $ as $\sin(\frac{x}{n}) \lt \frac{x}{n}$. And $ \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+x^2} = arctan(x)|_{0}^{\infty} = \frac{\pi}{2} \lt \infty$. Therefore you have (i).

Now fix $x$, note that $\lim_{n \to \infty} nsin(\frac{x}{n}) = x$, hence $\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n = \frac{1}{1+x^2}$. Therefore you have (ii).

By analysis in (i), you have already found such a $g$, so you can switch the limit and the integral(you cannot do this without convergence theorems!) and conclude that the answer of $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int nsin(\frac{x}{n})[x(1+x^2)]^{-1}$ is $\frac{\pi}{2}$ as computed in (ii).